# Facebook Silverlight application invalid method (HTTP verb)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi 
I made a simple application in Silverlight to facebbok with the facebook C# SDK, and it runs fine in a localhost. I have published on a server and know start the problems. When I try to run the application from the facebook I get the this messege (405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.)

anyone have any ideias of what is the problem ??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like  server/IIS/Web server configuration. Try hosting the web site in an iframe locally and see if you can get there...