# Facebook c# application: Facebook can not access my silverlight application on localhost

Tags: c#, iis-7, silverlight-3.0, facebook

Hi i am trying to write a silverlight applicaiton on Facebook. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have created a silverlight application and VS created a test page for it automaticly. I can acces and test my application on localhost (I have installed iis7 with default settings on win7x64 fresh install). I am publishing the test page to wwwroot and everything works on localhost. But when i try to access my application from Facebook i am getting this error:

"HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used."

But if i create a ASP.NET application and publist it same way it works.
So what sould i do?

Best reagrds

Olcay Ertas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried spoofing your host? I do not know if it is the case anymore, but in the past, Facebook refused to interact with http://localhost/. By editing my hosts file, I was able to get Facebook to interact with my local environment without having to push to a publicly accessible server.

Just [edit your hosts file](http://dotnetdawson.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/making-it-easy-to-edit-your-hosts-file/), putting in something like my.localhost.com, restart your browsers, and put that domain in to your Facebook app. It could work... apologies if it doesn't.

Comment: I dont think it is about Facebook. Because Facebook can access ASP.NET application page on my localhost. I think the problem is exacuting a program on my localhost. It has to do with permissions i ges.

Comment: Oh, I see! I apologize for not understanding you the first time around. This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803966/facebook-silverlight-application-invalid-method-http-verb

Comment: Thanks anyway for answering. I couldn't solve the problem. But i have bought a .Net 4 host and uploaded my application and it works fine.